# How to implement the compass for AR (augmented reality) view in iPhone like in Buuuk app

Tags: iphone, augmented-reality

We have been facing difficulty in implementing the compass view (circular view at the bottom of the AR screen with places in right direction) in AR like in Buuuk app. We are using the iphonearkit fraemwork as given in http://code.google.com/p/iphonearkit/.

Does anyone have a clue about how to implement it?

Comment: Why dont you try it yourself first and if you fail, post your code and any related questions. Asking for the complete code seems a little lazy.

Answer (score 0):

It's just some simple trigo calculation.

1. subclass drawRect
2. set a radius
3. draw a translucent circle
4. loop through the POIs, and get the maximum distance.
5. given that the maximum distance will end up at the perimeter of the circle, calculate the distance from the center for each POIs
6. use the distance from center and bearing of each POIs, and bit of trigo calculation to find the x,y coordinate